# Java design patterns: Pipeline and immutability

Tags: java, design-patterns, etl, backend, stream-processing

I'm working on a lightweight framework for my backend services to support a pipeline-like processing.

- In the pipeline, each stage is essentially a `Function<IN, OUT>` where `IN` is the `OUT` of the previous stage.
- Each stage can set its result to the data model (let's call it `Record`)
- Although the input is `IN` (the previous stage's output), each stage can look at all previous results so far.

**My question:**

So essentially, each stage can set its result to the data model and can get all other results so far. That makes the model being shared and mutable among all components in the pipeline.

Would it be considered an anti pattern? If so, what changes will you make in my architecture?

Thanks

Comment: Each stage can still create a new Record object

Comment: kinda looks like `List` implementation

Comment: @emotionlessbananas, can you elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pipeline design is good when the components in the line are and remain independent of each other. You see it used for example in web server filter chains (like Apache httpd filters, or Java servlet filters): each "link" in the chain can inspect the request and response and potentially make modifications.

The pipeline design quickly goes bad, when the components develop *hidden dependencies* between each other. A hidden dependency is when one link in the chain uses the results from a computation that is done in an upstream link. This dependency is not captured by the type system, or covered by tests, and frequently it's not even documented. If a programmer now modifies or refactors the code for the upstream link, there's a good chance the downstream code breaks. In a large system that multiple developers work on, hidden dependencies will happen quickly, and result in code that is brittle and hard to understand.

If you see hidden dependencies form, it would be better to replace the pipeline design  with a design that makes the dependency graph explicit.

Comment: So basically it's 3-steps pipeline. `A->B->C`. The thing I'm baffled about is: On one hand `B` needs `A`'s result. On the other hand, I don't want `B` to transform `A`'s result. One option could be to clone() the object or to serlialize it but it seems an overhead to me. Another, quite similar idea is to create a "thin" object (sort of like a DTO) only with the relevant data for `B`. Is that a reasonable approach?

Comment: If you don't want B to modify the result from A, it can simply pass it on without modification.

Comment: Yes, my question was if that's an anti pattern. That is, B potentially can change A's result since it's mutable (probably)